# how to create only two options available selected date

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want set just two options available date in devexpress dateedit.

when page load, i want set two option date available.
(1)available date from bind database
(2)available date from datenow.

this is my code. and not work.

```
<dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="dtOld" runat="server" Width="340px"></dx:ASPxDateEdit>
DateTime dateOld = dataBinds.dtOld; //14-10-2014
DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now; // 17-10-2014
dtOld.Date = dateNow;
dtOld.Date = dateOld;
```

please corrected my code. thanks...

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: i just want set two options date availabel 1 = date of 14, 2 = datenow.. in devexpress dateedit